# Difference between int* ptr and int(* arr)[3] =&a

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

```
int arr[3]={1,2,3};
int* ptr;
ptr=arr;
```

Is this same as

```
int a[3]={1,2,3};
int(* arr)[3] =&a;
```

If not, whats the difference?

Comment: Please re-read the chapter for arrays and integers in your favorite C book.

Comment: I did. Still getting confused. @SouravGhosh

Comment: Did you try to build the second one?

Comment: Right. and by build, @StoryTeller means, compile.

Comment: I am still not clear. The firstcase assigns ptr as a pointer to the first element of array.

The second case is also assignig a pointer arr to array.@SouravGhosh   @StoryTeller

Comment: @SahibSingh.: Tried to clarify a bit.

Answer (score 1):

In the  first case,

```
 int arr[3]={1,2,3};
```

`arr` is an aray of 3 integers and you're initializing the values by the brace-enclosed list `{1,2,3}`. All good.

In the second case,

```
 int(* arr)[3] ={1,2,3};
```

`arr` is a pointer to an array of 3 `int`s, thus the initalizer is **wrong**, (for multiple reasons like type mismatch, excess initializer).

You can however, use it like

```
 int(* arr)[3] = & (int []){1,2,3};
```

where, this makes use of a compound literal. This "converts" the brace-enclosed list to an array, and then, you use the address of that array to initialize the LHS.

Comment: @downvoter, can you help me improving the content, please?

Comment: Okay so :
`int a[]={1,2,3};`
`int (*arr)[3]= &a;`

`int arr[3]={1,2,3};`
`int* ptr;`
`ptr=arr;`

Are these two same?

Comment: no, they are not same, check the types.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you compile the code you have written with the second statement is that -

> warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast.

This is not the right thing to do. Casting would make the compiler stop complaining but the problem is even bigger.

Now let's see how you can make it correct

```
int a[]={1,2,3};
int (*arr)[3]= &a;
```

The difference is the `arr` is a pointer to an array. And what you wrote earlier is assigning the decayed pointer of array to the pointer variable.

Arrays are not pointers (Pointers are not arrays) - in the first case the array is converted to pointer to the first element - so it is converted into pointer to the `int` and that is being assigned.

---

Further explaining things:

There are two things to know - one is known as array decaying and another is how pointer's type is important.

Most of the times (notice the word *most* - I am not saying *always* there are cases where it doesn't. For example when using as an operand to `&` the array decaying doesn't occur. Now notice here you have used `&` also. So what is array decaying?) array is converted into pointer to the first element of what it contains. Suppose it is `int arr[]={1,2}` then suppose you use `arr` in operation like `arr+1` where does it point to or what is it? It points to the second element of the array. This is the **address** of `arr[1]`. `*(arr+i)` is basically `arr[i]`.

Now you might wonder why the `arr+1` points to the second element? Why not something else?

Pointer arithmetic is done considering the type of thing it points to. Suppose here `arr` is an `int*` in cases where decaying works - now if you write `int *p = arr+1` then this `1` will make `p` point to `arr[1]`.

---

Here `&a` is of type?? Yes it comes naturally when it is said that there is no decaying here. This is of type `int(*)[]`. It's a pointer and it's type is `int(*)[]`. Now what error did you do? You were using initializer which results in `int` value and that is assigned to a pointer. is this good? Nope. There is a type mismatch and also why would you initialize variable with an integer? is it an address? or is it something valid? You don't know. This would lead to a problem when you try to access the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

In:

```
int arr[3]={1,2,3};
int* ptr;
ptr=arr;
```

`ptr` points to the array `arr` which is valid, because arrays decay to pointers to their first element in such a context.

In:

```
int(* arr)[3] ={1,2,3};
```

`arr` is a pointer to an array of 3 `int` elements, and you have too many initializers because a pointer is a scaler, and should be assigned a single value. It must either produce an error or warning, because it is a constraint violation.

Comment: `int a[3]={1,2,3};`  
`int(* arr)[3] =&a;`

If i re write my second code like this. Are the ptr=arr code and this one doing the same thing? @machine_1

Comment: Yes, but be aware that they have different types. Both pointers would hold the same address, but `ptr` has type `int *`, while `arr` has type `int (*)[3]`. `ptr` is a pointer to `int`. `arr` is pointer to an array of 3 `int`'s

Comment: Okay so am i right when i say that in the first case ptr can point to any int value but `int(* arr)[3] =&a` can only point to int arrays having 3 values?